# Is Eclipse Mars CDT support C++11 thread?

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, c++11, mingw

I have the following setup:

- Eclipse Mars 4.5 (Build id:20150621-1200)
- MinGW 201310 with g++ 4.8.1
- Windows 10

I followed few post to add std=c++11 in Project property and make sure __cplusplus is 201103L. Here is the result:

- I can see that std::map compile and run ok.
- If I #include , there is no syntax error. But the declaration of thread in main() shows error "Type thread could not be resolved". Then I open up thread header file located in c:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/thread, it seems that the whole class is dimmed due to that _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS is undefined. If I manually define it in the path and symbols, then the thread class is fully defined. But there comes more errors in the thread itself. Did I missed something? Or if the C++11 thread isn't ready on eclipse+MinGW? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To get support for `std::thread`, you will want a MinGW build equipped with posix threading model support.

I'm not sure if there's a "classic" MinGW build with that feature, 
but it's available with MinGW-w64.

You can get a MinGW-w64 installation in a [number of ways](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download), but the installer under the "Mingw-builds" link should be sufficient to get you started (and will let you pick which release GCC you want).

Comment: Thanks. I am going back to Visual Studio :)